# Automatically convert Moin Moin content to Sharepoint

Tags: conversion, sharepoint, wiki

I have quite a bit of content in a [Moin Moin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoinMoin) wiki, that I need to move to a [Sharepoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharepoint) wiki.  The content is mostly in nested formatted pages with a few files (Word, Excel, and Visio) as attachments.  Is there any way to atomically convert and move this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I wrote a custom C# program to scrape MoinMoin, and clean up the html, and 'Sharepoint-ize' the wiki links.  Manually copying and pasting this new html into sharepoint wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft don't provide much assistance for this scenario. I don't know about Moin Moin specifically but unless its widely used there is unlikely to be a third-party product that can do it for you either.

This is a [good article](http://www.workshares.co.uk/blog/2009/07/migrate-or-move-content-inside-sharepoint/) by Andrew Walmsley that gives you the pros and cons of your options.